# What is the best approach to handling db queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

**I'm sure what i'm currently doing is not optimal**, but I would really like to hear some opinions regarding how you should handle all db queries on a web application including the connection string.

At the moment, I have a `classes` directory that has a file for each class and I have another directory called `db` that includes a `conn.php` which has the connection string and the other files on the `db` directory are like in the `classes` directory, one for each class but to handle the mysql queries.

So basically I have all db queries per class in one file and whenever I need to query something from the class file, I call the function on the db file

I include each db file in the corresponding db file, for example in the `user.class.php` file you will find `include('db/user.db.php')`.

Also, I include the `conn.php` file to each db file.

`user.class.php`:

```
include('db/user.db.php');
class User {
    public $fname;
    public $userid;

    function __construct($userid) {
        $this->user_id = $userid;
        $this->fname = DB_GetFirstName($userid);
        }
}
```

`user.db.php`:

```
include('conn.php');
function DB_GetFirstName($userid) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT USR_FName FROM users WHERE USR_ID = '$userid'"));
    return $result[0];
}
```

`conn.php`:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname", $conn);
```

How do you handle it?

Comment: Sounds okay to me. You are separating Db Access from your Domain classes. How do you put that together then? Can you show some snippets from your User and UserDb classes?

Comment: Added some snippets, it doesn't look too elegant to me. I was also told I should open a connection to the db for each query, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right thing already by separating your Domain Layer from the Database Access Layer. But the way you put it together could be improved. Have a look at the [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) (TDG) pattern.

In the Table Data Gateway pattern one class encapsulates all the access to a specific table. This is kind of like your User.Db.php with the difference that the TDG is an actual class. Instead of a bunch of functions you group any related db access into that particular class. This has the immediate benefit that you can pass the instance to any class that needs it instead of hardcoding function calls into them.

Whenever you need to work with a specific table you use the TDG to fetch/modify rows from it. You can then either work with the returned recordsets. Or use a [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) to map the data from the recordset onto your Domain classes, e.g. your User class. For simple DataMappers crafting your own is fine. Once it gets more complex, you'll better of using an existing ORM.

An alternative to the TDG would be the [Row Data Gateway pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html).

There is a good introduction to TDGs (with a Zend Framework example) at

- http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns-table

and for Row Data Gateway

- http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-row

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Database Abstraction Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer). What you have done sounds like it's a better approach than raw SQL lines, so long as you are validating input and preventing injection attacks.

Popular PHP frameworks such as [Doctrine2 have built-in database abstraction layers](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html) which have been put under public scrutinized and cover off a lot of things you will probably end up doing yourself.

I advise to use an open-source layer such as mentioned above before creating your own, as there are very solid code bases already made for you. Don't re-invent the wheel. If you see a shortcoming, think about improving the project.

Comment: The more projects I do, the more I get to the conclusion that a Database Abstraction Layer is (most of the time) pointless. Granted, having to learn just one API over learning all the existing db vendor extensions is convenient. But then again, they are not that hard to figure out either and often provide greater flexibility. And I've never had to change the actual db, so that argument doesn't count.

Comment: I've had to change my database recently (Oracle bought out MySQL, changed the redistribution licence terms) and the DBAL really saved me when I moved to postgres. DBALs can add complexity, and does feel like having training wheels on. However, I'm not alone in my feeling they save you more than they cost you, especially when you consider security, flexibility, and DRY.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much of the db vendor specific code features you need. In one project we had to stuff so much oracle specific SQL into the queries that it basically made no sense choosing a DAL to work with the DB. And since they paid deity-knows-how-much money for the license, they'd also not change anytime soon. In that project we had only made the DB access a bit slower and gained almost no advantage. Should have used the OCI extension directly.

Answer (score 1):

For small projects i use very simple php class http://code.google.com/p/edb-php-class/

```
$result = $db->q("select * from `users`limit 3");

foreach($result as $a){
        echo $a['name'].' '.$a['surname'].' '.$a['email'].' '.$a['country'].'</br>';
}
```

for larger use a Database Abstraction Layer.